# Not able to create workflow in Sharepoint designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I am trying to create sharepoint designer workflow inn designer 2013 on sharepoint online site But whenever I select sharepoint 2013 workflow I get a issue saying "server side activities have been updated you need to restart sharepoint designer error"

I have tried below things from net :
Close SharePoint Designer 2013
Delete everything at %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache
Delete everything at %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Web Server Extensions\Cache
Go to SPD2013 options –> General –> Application Options –> Uncheck the “Cache site data across SharePoint Designer sessions”
Restart the SharePoint Designer and open/create the workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Do as follows:

1.Try to copy the file Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.Activities.Proxy.dll to the location `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache\<site-name>\<version-number>`.

2.Check your Programs list for Workflow Manager Client 1.0. If it's there, uninstall it.

3.Install the KB for SharePoint designer.

[January 12, 2016, update for SharePoint Designer 2013 (KB3114337)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3114337/january-12-2016-update-for-sharepoint-designer-2013-kb3114337)

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the SharePoint designer, you have to install the update provided by Microsoft for SP designer 13 (kb3114337).

You can also check this [SharePoint Designer Error](http://www.techrobbers.com/2019/03/sharepoint-designer-workflow-error.html)